# CodeIgniter help required! View not showing the array I passed. what went wrong?

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Controller  (blog.php)**

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller{
    public function index ()
    {
        $this->load->model("blogvisitor");
        $user['users'] = $this->blogvisitor->logvisit();
        // print_r($data);
        $this->load->view("userslist",$user);   
    }   
}
?>
```

**Model (blogvisitor.php)**

```
<?php
class BlogVisitor extends CI_Model {
    public function logvisit()
    {
        return [
["fname"=>"john","lname"=>"doe"],["fname"=>"Johnny","lname"=>"Doe"]
                ];
    }
}

?>
```

**View (userlist.php)**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Users List</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Users list</h1>
<table>
    <? foreach($users as $user): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $user['fname'] ?> </td>
            <td><?= $user['lname'] ?></td>
        </tr>   
<? endforeach; ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error**

> Users list
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: user
>
> Filename: views/userslist.php
>
> Line Number: 10

**And**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: user
>
> Filename: views/userslist.php
>
> Line Number: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change controller to:

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller{
    public function index ()
    {
        $this->load->model("BlogVisitor");
        $user['users'] = $this->BlogVisitor->logvisit();
        // print_r($data);
        $this->load->view("userslist",$user);   
    }   
}
?>
```

And view:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Users List</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Users list</h1>
<table>
    <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $user['fname'] ?> </td>
            <td><?= $user['lname'] ?></td>
        </tr>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

You must open and close php like `<?php ?>` and when refering to a model make sure it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Replace inside your view by below script.Or you can open short tag from your php.ini file.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Users List</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Users list</h1>
<table>
    <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $user['fname'] ?> </td>
            <td><?= $user['lname'] ?></td>
        </tr>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My program now showing array in view. I am asking about that. :(

Comment: I got output look like below. Users list

john doe
Johnny Doe

Comment: He isnt complaining about the error being shown, after all, no matter which environment you have there should be no errors what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your view code like this,

this line

```
<? foreach ($users as $user): ?>
```

to

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
 ^
```

And this line

```
 <? endforeach; ?>
```

to

```
 <?php endforeach; ?>
   ^
```

So final code is

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Users List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Users list</h1>
        <table>
            <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $user['fname'] ?> </td>
                    <td><?= $user['lname'] ?></td>
                </tr>   
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```